# Matching exact string or word in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to search for specific word strings or text in VSCode by using double quotes.  I trying to find for example occurrences of "Video" without seeing "video library" occurrences.  Any suggestions?

Comment: ctrl-f. Turn on case sensitivity.

Answer (score 13):

1. Ctrl+F
2. Turn on regular expression search (marked with red arrow)

[image]

You see in the screesnshot it matches exactly 'video' keyword

If you want case sensitivity, then turn on the arrow mark button
[image]

Comment: Why do you have the `$` in your regex?  I don't think we can assume `"Video"` is always at the end of the line.  Better to use `\b`.

Comment: It looks he don't want to search "video library", so I started with this post

Answer (score 7):

You have to toggle (enable) both "Match Case" and "Match Whole Word".

"Match Whole Word" will only search for exact matches and by matching case, you should be achieve your goal.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7kkg.png)